# Locale <=> Time/Date format in Tomcat logs?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat7, locale, java-7

I can't seem to change the locale / date format in the Tomcat logs when running it from Eclipse. It's using a 12-hour clock and I want it to use a 24-hour clock instead (language is English, which already is what I want). Here's what I have tried so far:

- Setting `LANG` and `LC_ALL` environment variables to `en_GB` in Tomcat's launch configuration
- Adding `-Duser.language=en -Duser.region=GB` to VM options in Tomcat's launch configuration
- Adding `-Duser.language=en -Duser.region=GB` to Eclipse's `eclipse.ini`
- Setting `-Duser.language=en -Duser.region=GB` as default VM arguments in the JRE configuration

<strike>If I run Tomcat from the shell, it works as expected by adding `-Duser.language=en -Duser.region=GB` to `%JAVA_OPTS%` in `bin\catalina.bat` - as for example [outlined here](http://knowm.org/set-tomcats-default-locale/) - but that doesn't affect Tomcat when it is running from within Eclipse, of course.</strike> *(Erratum: I couldn't reproduce this and have to assume that I erroneously ran Tomcat with Java 6 instead of 7)*

Used software: Tomcat `7.0.54`, Oracle JDK `1.7.0_60` (64-bit), Windows 8 (64-bit)

---

**Update:** Thanks to [Michael-O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696632/michael-o)'s answer, I was made aware of a change in [Java's locale-resolution](https://web.archive.org/web/20151110141716/http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2011/12/default-locale-changes-in-java-7.html) as of Java 7. Indeed, going back to Java 6 fixes my problem and gives me the 24-hour clock - but that is not feasible for my current project.

I've not been able to achieve the same with Java 7. Supposedly, you can return to the old locale-resolution by setting the system property `sun.locale.formatasdefault` to `true`, but *that does not seem to affect the time display in Tomcat 7's logging at all*. After a while I found [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8028233) in which it's stated fairly clear:

> (...) we lost the ability to decide on 24hour vs 12hour time depending on the locale, but we gained the ability to override the default format by providing a format string for the java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format property in logging.properties.

Thus, it seems, defining this format string manually is the (only?) way to go, and Michael-O also suggested that, so I'm accepting his answer.

After delving into the madness that is [`java.util.Formatter`'s syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), I have for now settled with this format string, which needs to be put in the VM options in Tomcat's launch configuration:

```
-Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="%1$ty%1$tm%1$td_%1$tH%1$tM%1$tS_%1$tL %4$4.4s %3$s %5$s %n"
```

Output:

```
151003_195915_359 INFO org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] 
151003_195915_375 INFO org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] 
151003_195915_375 INFO org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina Server startup in 1280 ms
```

Alternatively shorter, for [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) timestamps use:

```
-Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="%tFT%<tT.%<tL %4$4.4s %3$s %5$s %n"
```

Output:

```
2015-10-03T19:37:03.703 INFO org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] 
2015-10-03T19:37:03.703 INFO org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] 
2015-10-03T19:37:03.703 INFO org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina Server startup in 1189 ms
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional investigation and the ticket link. JUL remains a pain in the ass. One recommendation though: rather use the following formatter `%tFT%<tT.%<tL...`. That is easier to read and you get ISO 8601 for free.

Comment: I actually like my timestamps that way, but I know that's a bit eccentric :) Included your version above!

Comment: Guess what? I have just tried to pass that property to Tomcat in `setenv.sh`, `catalina.sh`, even directly to the Java command in `catalina.sh`, I simply cannot properly escape the spaces in the property value. This JUL shit drives me crazy, I have wasted two hours for this lousy task without result. I will evaluate: https://github.com/grgrzybek/tomcat-slf4j-logback

Comment: Here is a followup: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11308633/696632

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably been hit by [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20151110141716/http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2011/12/default-locale-changes-in-java-7.html) change in Java 7.

The only solution I see is a custom formatter for ISO 8601.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely the root cause! Going back to Java 6 (which I can't for this project) it works again. I'm still in the process of finding a solution...

Comment: @zb226, I am also pissed by that. The only solution I see is a custom formatter for ISO 8601. Why don't you issue a bug report with Tomcat to use ISO 8601 in the log output by default?

Comment: I might just do that, but I need to fully understand first. How can it be that it still works from the command-line? This suggests to me Eclipse being the culprit, not Tomcat.

Comment: @zb226 You can set `-Dsun.locale.formatasdefault=true` to restore the previous setting. Consider that Eclipse forks the VM and passes probably other properties in contrast to the command line.

Comment: Yea, I've read that, but tried it to no avail - in `eclipse.ini` as well as `_?JAVA_OPT(ION)?S` environment variables...

Comment: @zb226 In the Run configuration of your Tomcat instance in Eclipse.

Comment: Of course I had tried this as well. It all doesn't work. See my update for a new piece of information, suggesting why this cannot work at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you need to change the date format in `catalina.out`. Please modify your `logging.properties` as below.

For `org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter`:

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter
org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter.timeFormat = yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

For `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter`:

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = "%4$s: %5$s [%1$tc]%n"
```